# Nhibernate ICRITERIA syntax

Tags: c#, nhibernate, icriteria

I have the following sql :

```
       Select * from table where (Field1=1 and Field2=1) or (Field3=1)
```

How do i create the selection using NHibernate ICriteria
Regards Keld

Answer (score 3):

Use Restrictions.Or and Restrictions.And

```
Session
.CreateCriteria<Table>()
.Add(Restrictions.Or(
    Restrictions.And(
        Restrictions.Eq("Field1", 1),
        Restrictions.Eq("Field2", 1)),
    Restrictions.Eq("Field3", 1))
.List<Table>();
```

Comment: Thx, i thougt there could be a way joining 2 criterias